# Can we use the electrostatic force of repulsion to project object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics

My question is very simple. Can we use electrostatic force of repulsion to project objects; By charging that object(movable) with the same charge to another static object (non moving) in a close system so that all the resultant force is exercised only on the moving object setting it in motion?

Answer (score 1):

If they are opposite charges no even no matter the magnitude of the resulting force. If you have -2 and +4; the resulting is +2 with the attraction not repulsion

Comment: Sorry I meant "like charges" not "opposite charges". I will edit my question.

Comment: Okay in that way it very possible using the magnetic of the charges in the correct orientation will create a repulsion